# Is it recommended or good idea to have 2 diff./same circuit breaker(resilience4j) per message/api call?

Tags: circuit-breaker, resilience4j

In my micro-service, circuit breaker is present at a layer where external api call happens and my recorded exceptions are those which can happen during this external api call.
But my service timeout is configured at a layer way above this(where circuit breaker is present/configured) layer. I can't move circuit breaker up to the layer where timeout is configured or vice-versa.

Basically, I want to record this timeout exception happening at different layer.

Is it recommended or good idea to have 2 diff./same circuit breaker per message/api call?

Answer (score 1):

Check this for answer on github repo by the creator himself: https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j/issues/1060:

> Yes, you can do that.
> But you have to think about how exceptions are progapated through two CircuitBreakers.